# JavaScript return largest element (positive and negative check)

Tags: javascript

I have read through a lot but I still cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong.

I need to create a function that checks a list of numbers and see which is the largest. It also should cover negative values, duplicated values and an empty array.

This is the jasmine task that sends these 'tasks':

```
describe('List', function() {
  'use strict';

  var list;

  beforeEach(function() {
    list = new List();
  });

  it('should find the largest element', function() {
    var data = [1, 100, 32, 453, 21, 5, 23, 12, 90];
    expect(list.findLargest(data)).toBe(453);
  });

  it('should cover negative values', function() {
    var data = [-1, -123, -2, -6, -10000, -10];
    expect(list.findLargest(data)).toBe(-1);
  });

  it('should cover duplicated values', function() {
    var data = [-1, -123, -1, -6, -10000, -1];
    expect(list.findLargest(data)).toBe(-1);
  });

  it('should cover all duplicated values', function() {
    var data = [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3];
    expect(list.findLargest(data)).toBe(3);
  });

  it('should cover empty list', function() {
    expect(function() {
      list.findLargest([]); 
    }).toThrow('List cannot be empty.');
  });

});
```

This is my attempt:

```
var List = function() {
  'use strict';

  function findLargest(list) {
    var largest = [];

    if( list[i] > 0){
      for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        if (largest < list[i] ) {
            largest = list[i];
        }
    }
    console.log(largest);
    return 453; //First tried this, but it doesn't even go into this function
    //return largest; //Doesn't work
    }

    else if( list[i] < 0 ){
      console.log("negative");
      for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        if (largest > list[i] ) {
            largest = list[i];
        }
      }
      console.log(largest);
      return largest;
    }

    // else {
    //    throw("List cannot be empty.");
    // }

  }

  return {
    findLargest: findLargest
  };
};
```

This is the errors I get:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kq2WL.jpg

If I de-comment my `else`, I will just get:

```
List cannot be empty. thrown
```

It seems as though it not entering the function. I cannot see the problem, I'm to JavaScript sorry.

Comment: Where does `i` come from in the original `if`?

Comment: It comes from the array that jasmine sends me. My code awaits an array

Comment: Where does `i` come from when it's **outside** of `for` loop?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the basic mathematics functions to do this for you. No need for a seperate function.

`const highest = Math.max.apply( null, [1, 100, 32, 453, 21, 5, 23, 12, 90] ); // 453`

and

`const lowest = Math.min.apply( null, [-1, -123, -2, -6, -10000, -10] ); // -10000`

Comment: I cannot use pre defined functions, my task is to "build" my own code :/

Comment: Alright I see. I'll just give you the tip the that `Array.reduce()` can do all of the tests as well. I'll leave writing the compare function to you then. :) Also remember, that there's no logical difference between different 'instances' of the number 3. So the function to check `[ 1, 3, 3, 3 ]` can be the same as the one that checks `[ 1, 4, 5, -10 ]`. Or does the index of the duplicate matter?